# How to count some rows of a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, count

I got a MySQL table were multiple users can click a button to accept something.
After that, the information get saved with the following data.

```
uid (ai, primary key)
user_uid (id of user)
object_uid (id of object you visit)
date_start 
date_end
```

I want to count how many people got `date_end` on the same `object_uid`.
So if 2 people have an entry in `date_end` it should count for example 2 people which have visited the same `object_uid`. But I have no clue how to do that and I don't know to google better, because I search for an answer for about 2 hours ago.

Greetings

PS: I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and output here?

Comment: I test your example/help below and will inform you by new updates :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of @Tim Biegeleisen I got the right direction for my problem.
The following code solved my problem.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table_name WHERE date_end IS NOT NULL AND object_uid = id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:

```
SELECT
    object_uid,
    date_end,
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_uid) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
-- WHERE object_uid IN (...)
GROUP BY object_uid, date_end
ORDER BY object_uid, date_end;
```

This would output a report of each object along with dates and the number of distinct users coincident on an object and ending date.  If you only want data for a single object, or selected list of objects, then uncomment and use the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, it's not the 100% correct answer for my question, but it helped me to find my answer. I will post the answer for my problem.